# WPF Date Picker Control for .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, wpf-controls, datepicker

Im developing an application in C#.Net 3.5 Sp1 under WPF.I need to implement the date picker in it.How can i get that control in WPF.How can i implement in XAML.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or .NET 4 you can use the [DateTimePicker](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker&referringTitle=Home) control in the [Extended WPF toolKit on CodePlex](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The extended [WPF toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) provides an implementation. You can use it or study the source code to help you create your own version.